# SendKeys not working on Google Chrome

Tags: c#, winforms, sendkeys

I have a simple WinForm app with a button, and on-click I am trying to populate search keyword on Google Chrome already running (on chrome window). When I execute this program and click the button, Chrome window get presented (restored from minimized) but the focus still remains on my WinForm app and `SendKeys` does not work.

Is there a better way to do this?

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("User32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName,
            string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("User32.DLL")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IntPtr chromeHandle = FindWindow("Chrome_WidgetWin_1", null);
            if(chromeHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Chrome is not running");
                return;
            }
            SetForegroundWindow(chromeHandle);
            SendKeys.SendWait("search term");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If I were you I'd look at adding a Web Browser control to the form. Then you can interact with it directly via the DOM. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-add-web-browser-capabilities-to-a-windows-forms-application

Comment: I actually need my winforms app to interact with Google chrome running separately.